# How to fix "The import org.apache.poi cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, apache-poi

I want to make use of Apache-POI in my code, but am getting an error message `The import org.apache.poi cannot be resolved` at the import statement
`import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;`

I am a beginner with a freshly set up Visual Studio Code v1.30.2, Maven 3.6.0, Java JRE 1.8.0_201.

I have activated the following extensions:
Debugger for Java, 0.16.0
Java dependency viewer, 0.3.0
Java extension pack, 0.5.0
Java test runner, 0.14.0
Language support for Java (TM), 0.37.0
Maven for Java, 0.14.0

I entered these statements in the pom.xml in the dependency section:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I've also tried with other POI versions, e.g. 3.10-FINAL.

I'm too new to Java, Maven and VSCode to be sure I've included all the necessary information to point to a solution. Please help me :)

I've run `mvn compile`, with this result:

```
C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents\Java\project2>mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< MYNAME.project2:project2 >---------------------
[INFO] Building project2 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ project2 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents\Java\project2\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ project2 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents\Java\project2\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/Java/project2/src/main/java/MYNAME/project2/App.java:[12,1] package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/Java/project2/src/main/java/MYNAME/project2/App.java:[13,37] package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/Java/project2/src/main/java/MYNAME/project2/App.java:[14,37] package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/Java/project2/src/main/java/MYNAME/project2/App.java:[46,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class XSSFWorkbook
  location: class MYNAME.project2.App
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/Java/project2/src/main/java/MYNAME/project2/App.java:[46,45] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class XSSFWorkbook
  location: class MYNAME.project2.App
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/Java/project2/src/main/java/MYNAME/project2/App.java:[48,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class XSSFSheet
  location: class MYNAME.project2.App
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/Java/project2/src/main/java/MYNAME/project2/App.java:[55,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setCellValue(java.lang.String)
  location: variable cell of type com.google.common.collect.Table.Cell
[INFO] 7 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.549 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-30T09:41:45+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project project2: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/Java/project2/src/main/java/MYNAME/project2/App.java:[12,1] package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/Java/project2/src/main/java/MYNAME/project2/App.java:[13,37] package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/Java/project2/src/main/java/MYNAME/project2/App.java:[14,37] package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/Java/project2/src/main/java/MYNAME/project2/App.java:[46,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class XSSFWorkbook
[ERROR]   location: class MYNAME.project2.App
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/Java/project2/src/main/java/MYNAME/project2/App.java:[46,45] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class XSSFWorkbook
[ERROR]   location: class MYNAME.project2.App
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/Java/project2/src/main/java/MYNAME/project2/App.java:[48,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class XSSFSheet
[ERROR]   location: class MYNAME.project2.App
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/Java/project2/src/main/java/MYNAME/project2/App.java:[55,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method setCellValue(java.lang.String)
[ERROR]   location: variable cell of type com.google.common.collect.Table.Cell
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/
```

I've also pasted the full output of `mvn -X compile` [here](https://pastebin.com/GWpk3pDz)

I've pasted my full `POM.XML` [here](https://pastebin.com/k3N4XPYq)

In my local folder C:\Users\MYUSERNAME.m2\repository\org\apache there is **no subfolder** poi.

Comment: This is odd!  When I downloaded the JAR file corresponding to poi-ooxml 4.0.1 from Maven Central, the class you are trying to import is present and has that package.   Have you checked the JAR file that maven has downloaded to your local "m2repository" tree?    Try examining the JAR file to see if it is complete / correct.

Comment: In my local folder `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\.m2\repository\org\apache` there is no subfolder `poi`.

Comment: could you please post your full `pom.xml`

Comment: OK - so *somehow* Maven hasn't downloaded the artifacts that it needs.  Are you running disconnected from the internet?  Or behind a firewall that blocks internet access?  Do you need to configure Maven proxy settings?  Try running with the -X option to see if it is attempting to download ...

Comment: @ayZagen I added the POM.xml to my question.

Comment: @StephenC I added the output of mvn -X compile to my post. I have searched through it and don't see any sign that Maven is trying to download the files. There's only `[ERROR] /C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/Java/project3/src/main/java/MYNAME/project2/App.java:[12,1] package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks all contributors, and especially to @ayZagen (who pointed me towards the pom.xml).

It turns out that I had inserted the dependencies for poi into the dependencies section of

```
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
```

rather than into the correct section `<project> <dependencies>`.

When **I moved my dependencies to the correct section**, maven downloads POI and that part of the code compiles.

Sorry for taking people's time over a trivial error. Thank you for helping me to find out, and asking the right questions! This was a very positive experience!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Try moving poi dependencies to the root `dependencies` tag.

Run `mvn compile`

> The first time you execute this (or any other) command, Maven will
>   need to download all the plugins and related dependencies it needs to
>   fulfill the command. From a clean installation of Maven, this can take
>   quite a while (in the output above, it took almost 4 minutes). If you
>   execute the command again, Maven will now have what it needs, so it
>   won't need to download anything new and will be able to execute the
>   command much more quickly.

[Maven: Getting Started](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html)

Comment: The first time I run `mvn compile` I get BUILD FAILURE, see details in my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error log there are 2 possibilities

1. ***Network issue***.
   Maven is not able to download the jar files from its repository, so there is no **POI** library at **.m2** folder 
   Solution: Check the network/ Internet.
2. ***Files corrupted***. This happens if file(s) got corrupted.

   Solution:  delete the folder `org.apache.poi` inside **.m2** folder. the Right click on project(from Eclipse) --> `Maven` --> `Update project`. 
   Then `clean` & `refresh` project, then Run command **`Maven clean install`**